# How exactly callbacks get their arguments?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, parameter-passing

I have trouble understanding how callbacks in JavaScript get their arguments. Or in other words: how to implement a higher-order function so its callback accepts for instance a standard `err` and `data` arguments.

Like [in this article on asynchronous JavaScript](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript) in the example of a callback **used in a usual way** (and I know it's usual because I see exactly this pattern used in Node.js moongose (i.e. [for creating data in db](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create))):

```
function getData(options, callback) { 
    $.get("example.php", options, function(response) { 
        callback(null, JSON.parse(response)); 
    }, function() { 
        callback(new Error("AJAX request failed!")); 
    }); 
} 

// usage 
getData({name: "John"}, function(err, data) { 
    if(err) { 
        console.log("Error! " + err.toString()) 
    } else { 
        console.log(data); 
    } 
});
```

how exactly the callback gets arguments `err` & `data` based on how `getData()` function is declared above?

Comment: how exactly the callback gets arguments err & data? You're giving it to it, line 3 and line 5

Comment: When you call `getData`, you're passing the entire `function(err, data)` function as the second argument. If you look at the `getData` function, this is what's referred to as `callback`, and still takes two arguments.  If your response is sucessful, the `err` part of the function becomes null and the `data` part becomes `JSON.parse(response)`.

Comment: But exactly how it becomes null and data? There's nothing there in the time of passing. How console.log(data) gets passed JSON.parse(response)?

Comment: OK. Sorry @LinasMickevicius for being thick. Line 3 and 5. It finally got through to me. I guess my brain is more wired for synchronous and imperative. I hate this functional thing within a thing within a thing hell. Thanks for being patient

Comment: It just takes time to sink in and before you know it, it will feel completely normal and ordinary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arguments are passed to a function when that function is called.

```js
function foo(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
}

foo("This is the value");
```

This is still true when it is a callback function.

```js
function foo(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
}

function bar(callback) {
    callback("This is the value");
}

bar(foo);
```

And it is still true when the callback function is called by code written by someone else that exists in a library you aren't examining the source code of.

Comment: I'm not asking when but how. In your example you are passing some completely arbitrary "foo", but in the mongoose's or the article's example it's somehow a very specific thing: error as the first argument and data (i.e. an object created in a database) as the second. The other example could be a callback in Array.prototype.forEach - it also accepts 3 very specific arguments (currentValue, index, array). I'm asking how is it done.

Comment: Read the last sentence in the answer, it's done in exactly the same way but by the implementor of the library / that specific function behind the scenes.

Comment: I have to be too stupid for this. Arguments are passed to a function when that  function is called - so what is exactly passed when the callback is called in moongoose model.create(). What is err and data in the exact time of calling? How can data be the object retrieved from a database if it's not even commited there at that point?

Comment: OK. I got it more or less. @LinasMickevicius and just to straight it out completely - so in the article cited this implementator would be the getData() function that decides what goes in err and data on line 3 and 5, right?

Comment: OK. Now it really finally got through my (considerably more thick than I thought) skull. It was a simple matter of forgetting that callback is a function declared on the fly - so even if it looks somewhat like you call something with 2 arguments (function(err, data)), there's nothing called at this moment, only declared (and called in getData() on the lines 3 and 5). What a regression after 2 months of continuous JS writing o_O!